# Upserting more than one object via Apex Data Loader

Tags: data-loader

As the title suggests I would like to know whether it is possible to upsert more than one object.

Example :

Updating **Account.Site** and **Contact.FirstName** together in a single apex data loader process.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot insert , update more than one objects record using dataloader at a time. However you can use [upsert operations](http://youtu.be/XsdPPQ-WT58) , or update operation twice to update existing records with new value.

You can check [this article to know more about how Upsert works using Dataloader and Apex.](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/all-about-upsert-and-external-id-in-dataloader-and-apex-videos/)